# Как подключить модуль jmeter к yandex-tank

Tags: яндекс-танк, jmeter, нагрузочное-тестирование

Всем привет. Не совсем понимаю,как подключить созданный jmx к яндекс танку и какими примерно конфигами заполнить load.yaml для подключения jmeter? В сети нашел такой пример

```
    jmeter:
  enabled: true
  package: yandextank.plugins.JMeter
  jmx: ammo.jmx
  jmeter_path: /var/loadtest/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/jmeter
  buffered_seconds: 0
  ext_log: none
  variables:
    protocol: http
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 8080
    path: /path/to/endpoint
    thread_rpm: 300
    loops: 20
    texts: scenarios.csv
```

Делал по этому примеру,все равно не запускается.

Answer (score 1):

в jmeter_path указывается полный путь к установленному JMeter от корня /
так же и JMeter_pluging, а так же рекомендую указывать версию JMeter
пример рабочего кода вот такой:

```
jmeter:
  enabled: true
  jmx: /home/load/dz_load_tank/scripts/https-get.jmx
  jmeter_path: /usr/share/jmeter5/bin/jmeter
  buffered_seconds: 10
  jmeter_ver: 5.1
  ext_log: all
```